# Positivity of bounded form $\phi$ on C*-algebra $A$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, c-star-algebras, banach-algebras, bilinear-form

I am reading Lectures on von Neumann algebras by Stratila and Zsidò. I don't know what to do with exercise 5.1, do you have any tips?

Let $A$ be a $C^*$-algebra and $\phi$ a bounded form on $A$. If there exists an $a \in A$, $a>0$, such that $\phi (a)= ||\phi||\, ||a||$, then $\phi$ is positive.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rescaling $a$, you may assume that $\|a\|=1$. Then the condition tells us that $\phi$ attains its norm in a positive element of norm $1$.

We may moreover also assume that $A$ is unital (why?).

We show that this automatically implies that also $\phi(1)=\|\phi\|$.

Indeed, all you have to do is choose $\lambda\in \mathbb{C}$ with $|\lambda| = 1$ such that $\lambda\phi(1-a) \in [0, \infty[$. Then, since $\|a + \lambda(1-a)\| \le 1$ (why?), we have
$$\|\phi\| = \phi(a)  \le \phi(a)+ \lambda \phi(1-a) = \phi(a + \lambda(1-a)) \le \|\phi\|$$
and thus $\|\phi\| = \phi(a) + \lambda\phi(1-a) = \|\phi\| + \lambda\phi(1-a)$ so that $\phi(1-a)=0$, i.e. $\phi(1) = \phi(a) = \|\phi\|$.

Now, you can invoke the well-known fact that if $\phi$ is a bounded functional on a unital $C^*$-algebra that attains its norm in the identity, then it is automatically a positive functional. This is proven in every text on $C^*$-algebras.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. However, it is not clear to me why one can assume that the $C^*$-algebra is unital.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Extend your functional to the unitisation (Hahn Banach). Apply the argument from the unital case to see that it is positive, and then restrict back to the original algebra. Restrictions of positive maps remain positive.